# Expectile regression in Implicit Q-Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, offline-reinforcement-learning

I am reading Kostrikov et al.'s "[Offline Reinforcement Learning with Implicit Q-Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.06169)" but got stuck understanding one particular transformation they use.

They describe the loss function they would like to minimize:

[image: Eq. (4)]

which is essentially the loss function for Q-learning, with a small twist: because they are interested in offline learning, the actions $a'$ considered for the maximization are only those produced by the behavior policy $\pi_\beta$ (essentially, the policy represented by the the offline dataset $\mathcal{D}$ we are learning from) with probability greater than 0.

At this point the authors propose to approximate the maximization with *expectile regression*. They explain expectile regression to be realized by the following minimization of a loss function $L_2^\tau$ (not replicated here for brevity), where $\tau \in [0,1]$ is a target expectile:

[image]

The intuition is that if $\tau$ is, say, 0.75, then the minimizing $m_\tau$ is a point such that $P(X < m_\tau) \approx 0.75$. So if you choose a high value of $\tau$ close to $1$, you are in effect computing a maximum value of $\mathcal{X}$ by stochastic gradient descent, using samples $x \sim X$, without necessarily having to iterate over all values of $X$.

Now comes the part that I don't understand. They apply the idea of expectile maximization to Eq. (4) and obtain a new loss function:

[image]

the argument being that minimizing this loss function with respect to $\theta$ is approximately equivalent to minimizing the loss function in Eq. (4) with respect to $\theta$. While I can see the intuition, I am not seeing exactly how this is mathematically justified.

I think they are using this transformation:

$E_{(s,a,s')\sim \mathcal{D}}\left[\left(r(s,a) + \gamma max_{a'\in \mathcal{A}\;s.t. \pi_\beta(a'|s')>0} Q_{\hat{\theta}}(s',a') - Q_\theta(s, a)\right)^2\right]=$
$E_{(s,a,s')\sim \mathcal{D}}\left[\left(max_{a'\in \mathcal{A}\;s.t. \pi_\beta(a'|s')>0} \left(r(s,a) + \gamma Q_{\hat{\theta}}(s',a') - Q_\theta(s, a)\right)\right)^2\right]$

and then, by some step I don't understand, they approximate that by

$E_{(s,a,s',a')\sim \mathcal{D}}\left[L_2^\tau\left(r(s,a) + \gamma Q_{\hat{\theta}}(s',a') - Q_\theta(s, a)\right)\right]$

How can that be shown?

Answer (score 2):

Because $argmin_{m_\tau} E_{x\sim X} \left[L_2^\tau(x - m_\tau)\right]$ approximates $max_{x \in X} \hspace{0.1cm} x$, then

$E_{(s,a,s')\sim \mathcal{D}}\left[\left(max_{a'\in \mathcal{A}\;s.t. \pi_\beta(a'|s')>0} \left(r(s,a) + \gamma Q_{\hat{\theta}}(s',a') - Q_\theta(s, a)\right)\right)^2\right]$

is approximated (with $\tau$ sufficiently high) by

$E_{(s,a,s')\sim \mathcal{D}}\left[argmin_\theta E_{a'\in \mathcal{D}}\left[L_2^\tau\left(r(s,a) + \gamma Q_{\hat{\theta}}(s',a') - Q_\theta(s, a)\right)\right]\right]$

which is then

$argmin_\theta E_{(s,a,s',a')\sim \mathcal{D}}\left[L_2^\tau\left(r(s,a) + \gamma Q_{\hat{\theta}}(s',a') - Q_\theta(s, a)\right)\right]$